# Python - time complexity O(N**2)

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

can anyone tell me where in code below, we get O(N**2):

```
def solution(X, A):
    assistant = list(range(1, X+1))
    assistant_sum = sum(assistant)
    helper = set()
    if X not in A:
        return -1
    if A.count(A[0]) == len(A):
        if A[0] == 1:
            return 0
        return -1
    for y in A:
        helper.add(y)
    sorted_helper = sorted(list(helper))
    if sum(sorted_helper[0:X]) == assistant_sum:
        helper = set()
    for index, i in enumerate(A):
        try:
            helper.add(i)
            if len(list(helper)[0:X]) == len(assistant) and int((list(helper)[0]+list(helper)[X-1])/2.0*len(helper)) == assistant_sum:
                return index
        except IndexError:
            pass
    else:
        return -1
```

Is there any way to check time-complexity online?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`helper` is a set which can be up to the same length as A. in your for loop `for index, i in enumerate(A)` you are then calling `list(helper)`

With the length of A being N, `list(helper)` is `O(N)`, `for index, i in enumerate(A)` is `O(N)`.

A statement of `O(N)` inside a loop of `O(N)` gives `O(N**2)`